# Trying to use try catch for args.length and op.length

Tags: java, arguments, operators

I'm struggling with the syntax on how to make my program catch the args and op length. I need them both to be exactly 3 (3 arguments and op must be 3 characters) and if they are not, I need it to print out the respective println message. I'm new to java so I apologize if my code looks unpleasant or grossly erroneous.

```
    import java.util.*;

public class dd{
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    if (args.length !=3)
    if (op.length !=3)
    {
        try
        {
            int = args.length ;
            System.out.println("ok");
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
            System.out.println("invalid number of arguments");
    }
    catch( NumberFormatException e )
    {
            System.out.println("invalid number of characters in operator");
    }
    finally
    {

    }

    String op = args[2];
        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        switch(op) {
          case "add":
            System.out.println(op1+op2);
            break;
          case "sub":
            System.out.println(op1-op2);
            break;



        } 
    }
    }
```

**Edit: I got the program to function as desired with simple if statements. My question now is how do I make the program function the same by using try catch? New code below**

```
    import java.util.*;

public class tester{
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    if (args.length != 3 ){
    System.out.println ("Invalid argument");
}
    String op = args[2];
    int op1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int op2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
{ 
    if (op.length() !=3){
    System.out.println ("Invalid op length"); 
}
    switch(op) {
        case "add":
            System.out.println(op1+op2);
            break;
         case "sub":
            System.out.println(op1-op2);
            break;

    } 
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this community is not a free tutor service where people sit down with you and teach you step by step how to fix the myriad of syntax errors in your code. Seriously: step back. Try to learn **one** concept after the other. Instead of throwing together stuff like this, creating a mess that neither you nor anybody else will be able to unfold.

Comment: The code doesn't compile because you're calling `op.length` before declaring `op`. And because `op` is a string, it should be `op.length()` (method call). What is your question?

Comment: Seriously: dont write 100 lines of code ... to then run the compiler. Instead write **minimal** amounts of code. Just enough so that you think "this should compile". Then run the compiler ... and see what it has to say. Fix all problems, write some more code, run the compiler again.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I didn't realize it was that bad.

Comment: Finally: you dont "catch" for the length of an array. You can query its length, and then your code makes decision based on that information. The exceptions you are catching here basically mean: you did something wrong in your code. You dont catch such exceptions - you write code that doesn't go wrong instead.

Comment: Maybe not myriads - but you have enough wrong code in there to easily sit down and talk an 30 to 60 minutes about it. And as said - that is **not** what this community is about. SO is not a replacement for you doing that learning part.

Comment: Mick, my question was how do I go about writing a code that will catch an invalid args and op length.

Comment: I do realize the code is not correct. I tried to get it as close as I could so SO could get the jist of what I was getting at. The syntax is killing me. Trying to self-learn.

Comment: Things that can help you further: 1) Use an IDE (e.g. Eclipse, NetBeans) for writing code; you get useful features such as formatting, autocomplete and suggestions for fixing errors. 2) Simplify the code: check for `args.length` and if it's correct, continue to the `switch-case` for checking the operation; use the `default` case for handling invalid operation values (wrong length or name).

Comment: Thank you, currently using notepad ++ and executing in cmd line. I will attempt your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

i don't sure if i understend you exacly, but try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    String op,args1;    //you need to declare the variables as string
    //you cant use the name args so i changed it to args1
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    op = s.nextLine();  //get the input from the user and put it in op
    args1 = s.nextLine();  //get the input from the user and put it in args1
    if (args1.length() == 3 && op.length() == 3)       //You need to use .length() to get the string length
    {
        System.out.println("\"args1\" length and \"op\" length is 3 !");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("one of the variables \"args1\" or \"op\" or both of them is'nt = 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced the top part of my code with what you presented but I got multiple errors for the bottom half. I have to use the try catch finally method to achieve my goal.

Comment: use it inside your class

Comment: why you need try catch you just want to check "args1" and "op" length am i right?

Comment: The idea is to learn how to use the try catch. I'm still working at integrating your code but getting multiple errors in my portion.

Comment: You can't realize this idea if you don't know the basics. I would recommend you go through a bit on java.